# c# Dotnet 2.0 CustomColumnStyle : putting a winforms panel inside a datagrid cell

Tags: c#, datagrid, button, panel, cell

All,

I realize that CustomColumnStyle is the way to customize columns of cells in a DataGrid. How would I use this to make each cell a Panel.

I would like each cell in a column to be a Panel, so I can add controls to it, like multiple buttons etc.

Thanks in advance for code.

-Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

correction, I mean "DataGridColumnStyle", not "CustomColumnStyle".